# Sinatra + Chartkick + Sequel gem, chart not updating

Tags: ruby, sinatra, chartkick

I'm running a very basic Sinatra server, which simply shows a Chartkick graph of some data I have through the Sequel gem. I'm noticing that the data on the chart doesn't seem to update unless I quit the Sinatra server script and rerun it. I don't really understand how that would be possible... the only non-normal thing option I'm using when reading my database using Sequel is the read-only option.. would that cause this?

Comment: can you show some of the code? sinatra doesn't auto-update when the server is running like rails does, though you can use rerun or shotgun gems

Comment: There's no code to show aside from, for example, `@db = Sequel.sqlite('../mydb.sqlite3', :read_only => true)` and `MyModel.where(:attribute => true).first`.. it's generic stuff. I tried shotgun and rerun, but it still won't update. It's almost like it's caching the database and not actually doing the calls I'm asking it to do.. I've also noticed this is happening on a different server I run that *doesn't* use read-only.

Comment: so, if you're running a single query only, how do you expect the data to update

Comment: It runs the query every time the page is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, from reading another post on here:

> First, by default, multiple processes can have the same SQLite
>   database open at the same time, and several read accesses can be
>   satisfied in parallel.
>
> In case of writing, a single write to the database locks the database
>   for a short time, nothing, even reading, can access the database file
>   at all.
>
> Beginning with version 3.7.0, a new “Write Ahead Logging” (WAL) option
>   is available, in which reading and writing can proceed concurrently.
>
> By default, WAL is not enabled. To turn WAL on, refer to the SQLite
>   documentation.

I currently have script A, which maintains a connection to the DB file and writes to it regularly, and script B, which is my Sinatra server that reads information from that DB file. I worked around this issue by using a block connection in my Sinatra script. I don't know how to turn on WAL with Sequel though...